# How successful has the Secretariat of State been in dealing with the Reformation?

Tags: reformation, counter-reformation

After the Reformation got into swing and Rome started losing significant numbers of followers Rome responded with the [Counter-Reformation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-Reformation) The basic plan was unfolded at the [Council of Trent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Council_of_Trent).

After the Council of Trent the [Secretariat of State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretariat_of_State_(Holy_See)) was heavily developed to create a diplomatic network of Nuncios.

How effective is the Secretariat of State? Would the Protestant movement have been more successful without their machinations?

Comment: **"It seems their master plan was to use diplomacy and statecraft to stem the rebellion. "** Can you provide a reference for that?

Comment: The Church also gained more members in Latin America than it lost due to Luther.

Answer (score 2):

**How successful has the Secretariat of State been in dealing with the Reformation?**

This is a non-question as the Secretariat of State for the Vatican was established for the purpose or working in an international diplomatic manner with other recognized sovereign countries, Catholic or otherwise.

> The origins of the Secretariat of State go back to the fifteenth century. The Apostolic Constitution Non Debet Reprehensibile of 31 December 1487 established the Secretaria Apostolica comprising twenty-four Apostolic Secretaries, one of whom bore the title Secretarius Domesticus and held a position of pre-eminence. One can also trace to this Secretaria Apostolica the Chancery of Briefs, the Secretariat of Briefs to Princes and the Secretariat of Latin Letters.
>
> Leo X established another position, the Secretarius Intimus, to assist the Cardinal who had control of the affairs of State and to attend to correspondence in languages other than Latin, chiefly with the Apostolic Nuncios (who at that time were evolving into permanent diplomatic representatives). From these beginnings, the Secretariat of State developed, especially at the time of the Council of Trent.
>
> The Secretariat of State is presided over by a Cardinal who assumes the title of Secretary of State. As the Pope’s first collaborator in the governance of the universal Church, the Cardinal Secretary of State is the one primarily responsible for the diplomatic and political activity of the Holy See, in some circumstances representing the person of the Supreme Pontiff himself.
>
> **The Section for General Affairs**
>
> In conformity with Arts. 41-44 of Pastor Bonus, the Section for General Affairs or the First Section is responsible for handling matters regarding the everyday service of the Supreme Pontiff, both in caring for the universal Church and in dealing with the dicasteries of the Roman Curia. It attends to the preparation of whatever documents the Holy Father entrusts to it. It enacts the provisions for appointments within the Roman Curia and keeps custody of the Lead Seal and the Fisherman’s Ring. It regulates the duties and activity of the Holy See’s Representatives, especially in relation to the local Churches. It attends to all that concerns the Embassies accredited to the Holy See. It supervises the Holy See’s official communication agencies and is responsible for publishing the “Acta Apostolicae Sedis” and the “Annuario Pontificio”.
>
> The First Section of the Secretariat of State is headed by an Archbishop, the Substitute for General Affairs, assisted by a Prelate, the Assessor for General Affairs. The position of the Substitute first appeared in the hierarchical listing of the Secretariat of State in 1814.
>
> **The Section for Relations with States**
>
> On the basis of Arts. 45-47 of Pastor Bonus, the Section for Relations with States or Second Section has the specific duty of attending to matters which involve civil governments. It has responsibility for the Holy See’s diplomatic relations with States, including the establishment of Concordats or similar agreements; for the Holy See’s presence in international organizations and conferences; in special circumstances, by order of the Supreme Pontiff and in consultation with the competent dicasteries of the Curia, provides for appointments to particular Churches, and for their establishment or modification; in close collaboration with the Congregation for Bishops, it attends to the appointment of Bishops in countries which have entered into treaties or agreements with the Holy See in accordance with the norms of international law.
>
> This Section began as the Congregation Super Negotiis Ecclesiasticis Regni Galliarum, set up by Pius VI with the Constitution Sollicitudo Omnium Ecclesiarum of 28 May 1793, in order to deal with the problems which the French Revolution posed for the Church. In 1814, Pius VII gave this office responsibility for the entire world and named it Congregatio Extraordinaria Praeposita Negotiis Ecclesiasticis Orbis Catholici. Some years later, Leo XII changed its name to Congregatio Pro Negotiis Ecclesiasticis Extraordinariis, which remained its title until 1967 when Paul VI separated this body from the Secretariat of State, calling it the Council for the Public Affairs of the Church. This Council was later replaced by the present Section for Relations with States.
>
> The Second Section of the Secretariat of State is headed by an Archbishop, the Secretary for Relations with States, aided by a Prelate, the Under-Secretary for Relations with States, and assisted by Cardinals and Bishops.
>
> [The Secretariat of State](https://www.vatican.va/content/romancuria/en/segreteria-di-stato/segreteria-di-stato/profilo.html)

Thus as we see the Secretariat of State was established as diplomatic Dicastery to deal with international affairs between the Holy See and other sovereign nations. The Vatican foreign diplomats are known as ***”Nuncios”***.

Prior to the Vatican being known as the Holy See in 1929, the Church’s sovereign statehood was known as the Papal States which existed until 1870.

> In the 1920s, the papacy – then under Pius XI – renounced the bulk of the Papal States. The Lateran Treaty with Italy (then ruled by the National Fascist Party under Benito Mussolini) was signed on 11 February 1929, creating the State of the Vatican City, forming the sovereign territory of the Holy See, which was also indemnified to some degree for loss of territory. - [Papal States](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papal_States)